# Pandas Select DataFrame columns using boolean

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use a boolean to select the columns with more than 4000 entries from a dataframe `comb` which has over 1,000 columns. This expression gives me a Boolean (True/False) result:

```
criteria = comb.ix[:,'c_0327':].count()>4000
```

I want to use it to select only the `True` columns to a new Dataframe.
The following just gives me "Unalignable boolean Series key provided":

```
comb.loc[criteria,]
```

I also tried:

```
comb.ix[:, comb.ix[:,'c_0327':].count()>4000]
```

Similar to this question answer [dataframe boolean selection along columns instead of row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25273180/dataframe-boolean-selection-along-columns-instead-of-row)
but that gives me the same error: "Unalignable boolean Series key provided"

```
comb.ix[:,'c_0327':].count()>4000
```

yields:

```
c_0327    False
c_0328    False
c_0329    False
c_0330    False
c_0331    False
c_0332    False
c_0333    False
c_0334    False
c_0335    False
c_0336    False
c_0337     True
c_0338    False
.....
```

Comment: don't you want `comb[criteria.columns]`?

Comment: comb[criteria.columns]  gives me "'Series' object has no attribute 'columns'"

Answer (score 48, accepted):

What is returned is a Series with the column names as the index and the boolean values as the row values.

I think actually you want:

this should now work:

```
comb[criteria.index[criteria]]
```

Basically this uses the index values from criteria and the boolean values to mask them, this will return an array of column names, we can use this to select the columns of interest from the orig df.

Comment: I am surprised to see, there is no shorter (more straightforward ) way of doing this.

Comment: There is, this answer is 5 years old and outdated. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57577991/11715606) below for the straightforward way

Comment: @johnDanger Nice answer, but I'm not sure I'd agree that going from "`m[f]` for row filtering" to "`m.loc[:,f]` for column filtering" is straightforward.

Comment: The "straightforwardness" in @johnDanger's answer is that you only need `criteria` once, and hence you do not need to define the variable separately (but can just use the expression itself ion `m.loc[:, expression_of_criteria_itself]`).

Answer (score 33):

In pandas 0.25:

```
comb.loc[:, criteria]
```

Returns a DataFrame with columns selected by the Boolean list or Series.

For multiple criteria:

```
comb.loc[:, criteria1 & criteria2]
```

And for selecting rows with an index criteria:

```
comb[criteria]
```

---

**Note**:
The bit-wise operator `&` is required (not `and`). See [Logical operators for boolean indexing in Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21415661/logical-operators-for-boolean-indexing-in-pandas?lq=1).

**Other Note**:
If the criteria is an expression (e.g., `comb.columnX > 3`), and multiple criteria are used, **remember to enclose each expression in parentheses!** This is because `&, |` have [higher precedence](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/precedence-associativity) than `>, ==, ect.` (whereas `and, or` are lower precedence).

Answer (score 7):

You can also use:

```
# To filter columns (assuming criteria length is equal to the number of columns of comb)
comb.ix[:, criteria]
comb.iloc[:, criteria.values]

# To filter rows (assuming criteria length is equal to the number of rows of comb)
comb[criteria]
```

Comment: The first answer looks the most elegant for masked column selection. The only trick is that one needs to do `comb.iloc[:, criteria.values]`, as a series is not a valid argument into `iloc` slicing of this type

Comment: I should have specified that I expected criteria to be a boolean list. Good catch.

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a boolean array to `loc` to indicate which columns should be kept and which not.

For example,

```
>>> df
    A   B   C   D    E
0  73  15  55  33  foo
1  63  64  11  11  bar
2  56  72  57  55  foo

>>> df.loc[:, [True, True, False, False, True]]
    A   B    E
0  73  15  foo
1  63  64  bar
2  56  72  foo
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this, it's cleaner

```
comb.values[:,criteria]
```

credit: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43291257/815677

Comment: Just to be clear, this returns an `numpy.ndarray`, and not a `pandas.DataFrame`.

Answer (score -1):

Another solution is to transpose `comb` to make its columns act as its index, then transpose on the resulting subset:

```py
comb.T[criteria].T
```

Again, not particularly elegant, but at least shorter/less repetitive than the leading solution.

Comment: There are already proposed solutions which are shorter/less repetitive than the accepted solution but also more elegant.

Comment: Seconding @JeanPaul... best to avoid transposes

Comment: @william_grisaitis What's the problem with transposes? Are they memory/compute intensive, or do you just find the `T` aesthetically displeasing, or ...?

Comment: @SethJohnson they can be really slow. not an expert, but that's my experience. if i had to guess, it's reallocating memory under the hood for everything (not a zero-copy operation).

Answer (score -1):

Another approach is to use Python's built-in `filter` function:

```py
def satisfies_criteria(column):
    return comb[column].count() > 4000


cols = filter(satisfies_criteria, df.columns)
df[cols]
```