# Python "TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'" for encoding categorical data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I am getting

> TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

when executing the below code for encoding categorical data in Python. Can anyone please help?

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')
y=dataset.iloc[:, 4]
X=dataset.iloc[:, 0:4]

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()
X[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X[:, 3])
```

Comment: What's in the csv file? In which line you got the TypeError?

Comment: Please add the corresponding stack trace to your question.

Comment: Tell use about the `dataset`?  I suspect its 'iloc' is expecting a string column label, not 2d array like slicing.    The error implies that a `slice` (e.g 0:4) is being used in as dictionary key, or something like that.

Answer (score 107):

`X` is a dataframe and can't be accessed via slice terminology like `X[:, 3]`.  You must access via [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) or [`X.values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html).  However, the way you constructed `X` made it a copy... so.  I'd use `values`

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
# dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')

dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10))
y=dataset.iloc[:, 4]
X=dataset.iloc[:, 0:4]

# Encoding categorical data
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OneHotEncoder
labelencoder_X = LabelEncoder()

#  I changed this line
X.values[:, 3] = labelencoder_X.fit_transform(X.values[:, 3])
```

Answer (score 8):

use Values either while creating variable X or while encoding as mentioned above

```
# Importing the libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Importing the dataset
# dataset = pd.read_csv('50_Startups.csv')

dataset = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 10))
y=dataset.iloc[:, 4].values
X=dataset.iloc[:, 0:4].values
```

Answer (score 4):

While creating the matrix `X` and `Y` vector use `values`.

```
X=dataset.iloc[:,4].values
Y=dataset.iloc[:,0:4].values
```

It will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, I'm curious about the reason of `TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'`?

Answer (score 1):

if you use .Values while creating the matrix   X and Y vectors it will fix the problem.

```
y=dataset.iloc[:, 4].values

X=dataset.iloc[:, 0:4].values
```

when you use .Values it creates a Object representation of the created matrix  will be returned with the axes removed.
Check the below link for more information

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.values.html

Answer (score 0):

I was getting same error (TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice') with below code:

```
included_cols = [2,4,10]
dataset = dataset[:,included_cols]  #Columns 2,4 and 10 are included.
```

Resolved with below code by putting iloc after dataset:

```
included_cols = [2,4,10]
dataset = dataset.iloc[:,included_cols]  #Columns 2,4 and 10 are included.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by changing X[:,3] to X.iloc[:,3] in label encoder

Answer (score -2):

Your x and y values ​​are not running so first of all youre begin to write this point

```
 import numpy as np
 import pandas as pd
 import matplotlib as plt

 dataframe=pd.read_csv(".\datasets\Position_Salaries.csv")

 x=dataframe.iloc[:,1:2].values 
 y=dataframe.iloc[:,2].values    
 x1=dataframe.iloc[:,:-1].values
```

point of value have publish