# Error message trying to change string to year

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to combine three fields to make a date, the year is currently string:
code to change string to datetime:

```
f2[:,'frt_eli_year'] = pd.to_datetime(f2['frt_eli_year'].astype(str), format='%Y',errors='coerce',utc=True)
```

error message:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'
```

Then code to join year, month, date:

```
f2[:,'test'] = pd.to_datetime(f2['frt_eli_year'].dt.year,f2['frt_eli_year'].dt.month,f2['frt_eli_year'].dt.day)
```

Appreciate the help, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake is in `f2[:,'frt_eli_year']`. Check this [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43291257/7891326). Basically it'll work if you change to `f2.loc[:,'frt_eli_year']`, or or since you want all rows, just `f2['frt_eli_year']`.

In total:

```
f2['frt_eli_year'] = pd.to_datetime(f2['frt_eli_year'], 
                                    format='%Y', errors='coerce', utc=True)
```

Comment: THank you missed loc wasnt in code: now trying to cobine 3 fields and get:

Comment: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: f2.loc[:'test'] = pd.to_datetime(f2['first_elig_year'].dt.year,f2['pol_eff_date_mth'].dt.month,f2['pol_eff_date_day'].dt.day)

Comment: f2.loc[:,'pol_eff_date_mth'] = f2['pol_eff_date'].dt.month
f2.loc[:,'pol_eff_date_day'] = f2['pol_eff_date'].dt.day

Comment: Since this is another issue, you should ask it in a new question.