# Remove multivalued columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe。

```
   A  B
0  2  3
1  2  4
2  3  5
```

If the value of a column has more than 2 different values, I will remove.
expect the output:

```
   A
0  2
1  2
2  3
```

Comment: What ave you tried till now?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.nunique()` and `.loc`, passing a boolean

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: 2, 1: 2, 2: 3}, 'B': {0: 3, 1: 4, 2: 5}})
df.loc[:, (df.nunique() <= 2)]
```

```
   A
0  2
1  2
2  3
```

An alternative approach (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29281815/pandas-select-dataframe-columns-using-boolean)):

```
criteria = df.nunique() <= 2
df[criteria.index[criteria]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `for` loop and `value_count` to get the result:-

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data= {'A':[2,2,3], 'B':[3,4,5]})
for var in df.columns:
    result = df[var].value_counts()
    if len(result)>2:
        df.drop(var, axis=1,inplace=True)
df
```

**Output**

```
    A
 0  2
 1  2
 2  3
```